# Disable mouse scrolling for the webpage

Tags: html, flash, web

I have a website using enjin.com website builder, and I have a page where you can go to play my game that is a .swf, but its html form, and the game requires mouse scrolling for some features and when I test it, the page also moves up and down, how can I disable mouse scrolling only on that specific page? I want the scroll bar on right of screen to still function as it does regularly though, so users can scroll if they really need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this css property:

```
pointer-events:none
```

For more detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Do I put that in the html code of the .swf or the pages code (idk how to edit the pages code on enjin, id have to figure that out on their forums prob)? I want to disable scrolling for the page but not on the .swf since some parts in the game require mouse scrolling (zooming in and out etc.)

Comment: oh, well, i tagged html and flash lol and i dont think the website is in javasript.